# Why is the size of a symlink equal to the size of it's path string?

Tags: ext4, symbolic-link, ls

I've read a different question regarding this where the answer was that a symlink stores the name and target + a few bytes for other metadata.

Using "ls -l dir" on ext4, why does the symlink size always equal to the length of the string path of the file it links to?

I've tried it with multiple different paths, different file names, different files, etc.

The size of its symlink always equaled the length of the path string.

Is it maybe because the file size is too small?

Is this the actual length of the content of the symlink file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the actual symlink file only contains its target, and nothing more.

The metadata (including that this is a symlink file) is not stored within the file itself for most filesystems (including `ext4`).

Also see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/609474/actual-content-of-a-symlink-file).

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful